# Excel change column format using macro

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-formula, office-2007, vba

If there is word COST in column name then change the column format to currency using macro for excel.

like if column name is - "Final Cost" or "Total Cost" or "Item Cost"
then change column format to currency.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
Public Sub FormatCostColumnsAsCurrency()

  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Set sht = ActiveSheet

  Dim rng As Range
  Dim i As Integer

  For i = 1 To sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count

      Set rng = sht.Cells(1, i)
      If InStr(LCase(rng.Text), "cost") > 0 Then
          sht.Columns(i).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
      End If

  Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Conditional Formatting`, no macro required.

1. Highlight a cell in the left column of your table.
2. On the `Home` section of the ribbon, click `Conditional Formatting`, then `New Rule`.
3. `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`.
4. Enter this formula. If your row headings don't start in A1, change accordingly: `=SEARCH("cost",A$1,1)`
5. Click `Format` and set `Number` to `Currency`, then click OK.
6. In the `Conditional Formatting Rules Manager`, set `Applies to` so that it covers your table.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Sub CurrFormat()
    Dim colHeader As Range
    Set colHeader = Range("A1:E1")

    Dim currCell As Range
    Set currCell = Cells.Find("COST")

    If Not currCell Is Nothing Then currCell.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"

End Sub
```